# I am developing Plugin at Shopware 6 but getting no changes at backend and frontend

Tags: shopware

I am following Shopware 6 Developers Training and following every single bit but getting no changes at the admin as well as frontend.

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, is your plugin installed and activated? Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @babita could you able to  see any changes